# What is the proof that linear operators can be treated as variables?

Tags: calculus, operator-theory, linear-transformations, differential-operators

I understand what a linear operator is, but I don't understand why you can just treat it as a variable.

Comment: Can you give a specific example as to what you mean?

Comment: $x'' + 3x'$ can be represented as $D(D+3)$ I see that it turns out to be the same thing, but is there a proof for this?

Comment: @Goldname I view it as composition of two operators

Comment: @Goldname: Let $C^\infty$ be the set of infinitely times continuously differentiable functions. You may now define $D : C^\infty\to C^\infty$ by $D(x) := x'$. Note that $x$ is a function here (in $C^\infty$) and that the operator $D$ is linear. We often leave away the parentheses in $T(x)$ when an operator $T$ is linear. You can now again apply $D$ to $Dx$. This gives $D(Dx) = x''$. We also write $D^2x = x''$. Now, you can also add operators to each other. If you add $D$ to $D^2$ you end up with $(D^2 + D)x = D^2x + Dx = x'' + x$.

Comment: You easily see that the result is the same if you apply $D$ to $D + I$ (where $I$ is the identity operator mapping $x$ to $x$). Indeed, $D(D+I)x = D(Dx + x) = D(x' + x) = Dx' + Dx = x'' + x'$ (the prime missing in the comment above). Here, we used the linearity of $D$. Hence, $D(D+I) = D^2 + D$. Thus, you can perform the same operations (addition, subtraction, mutiplication) as you are used with numbers. You can also multiply them with numbers: if $a$ is a number then the operator $aD$ is defined by $(aD)(x) = a\cdot D(x) = ax'$ (which is the function that maps $t$ to $ax'(t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is why can operators $f(A)$ for various functions $f$ be introduced for a linear operator $A$, this is called *functional calculus* for linear operators and can be done in some generality, but not to the extent of taking an arbitrary function of complex numbers and extending it to linear operators.

If the question is why is composition of linear operators analogous to multiplication of numbers, this is true only for collections of operators that all commute with each other.

Answer (score 1):

That is just the postfix operator 
$$
.'
$$ 
replaced by a prefix operator 
$$
D .
$$
So
$$
x'' + 3 x' = (x')' + 3 x' = D (D x) + 3 D x = (D + 3 ) (D x) = ((D+3) D) x = (D(D+3)) x
$$
where certain algebraic properties were used, like associativity or commutativity.